# Why does half the power in my mobile home only work when the oven is on?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Half of my power stopped working in my mobile home. When I went to turn on the stove (220v), the lights powered back up. Some are a little dim, but when I turn the stove off again, the lights turn off.

Comment: Call your power utility - you've lost an incoming phase. But if you NEED TO SHOUT, SHOUT AT THEM, not us.

Comment: Can you [edit] this to a) remove the upper-case; b) To clarify if it is:  "When I turned on my stove, half the power stopped working." or "My power stopped working.  When I turned on my stove, the lights powered back up.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question is about losing a neutral, this one is about losing a phase. Yes, both are about broken wires, but it's a different wire and it causes different problems.

Comment: Quite right. The solution is the same - call the power company - but the symptoms are different.  The lost phase is less emergency since you're not going to fry appliances, but none of your 240V loads will work, and that will suck if one is HVAC.

Comment: One thing to note here is the make of breaker box.   If it is Federal Pacific, it HAS to be changed. They are infamous for failing and cause fires.